# Set focus on element of other page imported with jQuery load method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, focus

I have `HeaderTemplate.html` which includes a logout button and a navigation menu. This page will be imported from different pages using jQuery like this:

```
$(function(){
    $("#headermenu").load("HeaderTemplate.html");
});
.
.
</head>
<body>
<div id="headermenu"></div>
```

After login, user will be redirected to `Welcome.html` which includes only Header page `HeaderTemplate.html`. I wanna set focus on logout button **only on this Welcome page** so the javascript focus() can't be in the `HeaderTemplate.html`.

The problem is, as HeaderTemplate.html is imported, javascript can't find the logout button's id no matter where I put the code in the page. I even tried like this.

```
<div id="headermenu"></div>
<script>
    document.getElementById('logout-button').focus();
</script>
```

but still doesn't work. How can I make this work? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `callback` method of [**.load()**](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
$("#headermenu").load("HeaderTemplate.html", function () {
    $('#logout-button').focus();
    //Or
    //document.getElementById('logout-button').focus();
});
```